# Close object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need help. I have HTML code like this,

```
<div class="close">Close</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table>

<div class="close">Close</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table>

<div class="close">Close</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table>
```

How can I do on jquery closing only current table, where user clicked on Close.
Thanks .

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? Remove from the DOM? Hide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your markup is going to stay as it is (with the `table` immediately following the `div`):

```
$(".close").on("click", function () {
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

You could make this a bit more efficient by delegating the event handler higher up the DOM tree (bind it to some common ancestor element and pass the `.close` selector as the 2nd argument to `.on()`).

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

***HTML***

```
<div class="close">Close</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table>

<div class="close">Close</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table>

<div class="close">Close</div>
<table class="table"><tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr></table>
```

***JS***

```
$('div.close').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

***http://jsfiddle.net/F3EXf/6/***

Answer (score 0):

You can close that in this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```